# What is this ffmpeg dependency error telling me and how do I fix it?

Tags: arch-linux, ffmpeg, yaourt

At some point, I had an error with dependencies and had to remove some forcefully with `pacman -Rdd libvpx libx264`.

I have since reinstalled them, however I get this error upon each `yaourt -Syua`:

```
error: missing 'libvpx.so=4-64' dependency for 'ffmpeg0.10'
error: missing 'libx264.so=148-64' dependency for 'ffmpeg0.10'
```

Here is what I did to track down the problem

```
~ $ pacman -Qs libvpx
local/libvpx 1.7.0-1
    VP8 and VP9 codec

~ $ pacman -Qs libx264
local/libx264 2:152.20171224-1
    Library for encoding H264/AVC video streams (8bit depth)
```

I do not get the error when I run `pacman -Syu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the error when you run pacman because these libraries are not part of the official repositories, they are dependencies of an [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ffmpeg0.10/).

Yaourt is *not* your package manager, it is an *AUR helper*: use it to help you install and manage AUR packages (or a better solution, use one that is [not insecure and buggy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table), like auracle).

You fix the errors by rebuilding the AUR package, ffmpeg0.10 and the requisite dependencies.

Comment: Already did as mentioned in question content. error persists. I just realized I only mentioned rebuilding the dependencies. I am not convinced this is the answer. Are you like the Arch Linux rep here? You give attention to anything I ask haha.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Have you rebuilt ffmpeg0.10 againts the (newly reinstalled) libs?